# "Decoding Failed: Syntax Error" after Magento 1.9.3 upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, supee-8788

I've had a few issues since updating our Magento site from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.

When we try to save attributes in the backend, we get a "Decoding Failed: Syntax error" message in red at the top of the backend.

We tried the new SUPEE-8788 patch on a different branch, and get the same issue.

Has anyone experienced this or know a fix?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Just fixed it now. For us it was a third party module that had an error in their javascript. Causing it to send a bad json object. I'd check your console log and see if you had any javascript errors when trying to save the product attribute.

Comment: That's right. I had to turn of Seo Layered Navigation from Ecommerce Team after installing patch SUPEE-8788.

Answer (score 3):

"Official fix from Ecommerce SLN:

Delete from `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\ecommerceteam\catalog\product\attribute\options.phtml` ...

```
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = <?php echo $uploader_block->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>;
var maxUploadFileSize = '<?php echo $uploader_block->getDataMaxSize() ?>';
```

...  to fix this issue.

Comment: It worked for me but would this removal introduce side effects?

Comment: This fix comes from Ecommerceteam support ... so it shouldnt have side effects.

Comment: i did not get this two line in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml

Comment: Wrong path ...

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\**ecommerceteam**\catalog\product\attribute\options.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Chrome console was spitting out errors related to Flash player not being able to render some elements.

As Chrome disabled Flash by default in the current version the fix was to enable flash for the Magento domain.

[image: How to enable Flash in Chrome]

After enabling Flash the product was able to be successfully saved.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution,
need fix Zend lib

http://qaru.site/questions/2319217/php7-json-and-zend-decoding-failed-syntax-error